# Vimeo API with IE7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, vimeo

I'm currently having issues using the Vimeo framework on IE7.

The first error I was receiving was JSON is undefined.  I was able to solve this by adding the JSON2 Javascript file for IE7 only.

Now I receive the following error:
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
froogaloop.min.js, line 1 character 256

The line in question is right here: b.contentWindow.postMessage(a,f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postMessage is an HTML5 feature and it is not available in IE7.

You can try using a polyfill, for example this: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

EDIT: Or you can use the Flash Embed Code which is compatible with IE7 as described here: http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding#universal-embed-code and use the alternate API.

Note that you have to include the FlashVars parameter to activate the API. Here are some tips that might help:

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:43266

http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:42631

Comment: Thanks.  We're going to try this out shortly.